# maven assembly- sub folder

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I want to use maven assembly plugin
assembly

```
     '<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>dist</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/main/dist.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>'
```

my descriptor file is :

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
 <id>dist</id>
 <formats>
 <format>dir</format>
  </formats>
<files>
<file>
   <source>pom.xml</source>
   <outputDirectory>/ET</outputDirectory>
</file>

</files>

 </assembly>
```

the result is folder hierarchy is:
 ET->  MyProject-MySnapshot-dist  ->    pom.xml

I want the result to be :
 ET->pom.xml

how can i configure it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add

```
 <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
```

to your assembly descriptor.